# JS: Can I return early from nested functions without using throw

Tags: javascript, function

I would like to "abort" (return) a function early from a nested function. It does not need to return any value. I would like it to not be verbose (like a throw) and not have additional if checks after each check function. The checks rely on the order in which they are called in, so they can't recycle the same `stop` variable and have one `if` check to abort.

Would something like that be possible ?

#### Throw

```js
const groupCheck = () => {
  const group = "MyGroup",
    type = "SUB"
  if (!undefined)
    throw new Error(`GROUP (${group}) does not exist. handle${type} failed.`);
}

const handleSUB = () => {
  groupCheck();
  console.log("I ran")
}
handleSUB();
```

#### Check variable

```js
const groupCheck = stop => {
  const group = "MyGroup",
    type = "SUB"
  if (!undefined) return true;
}

const handleSUB = () => {
  let stop = true;
  stop = groupCheck(stop);
  if(stop) return;
  console.log("I ran")
}
handleSUB();
```

Comment: `handleSUB` and `groupCheck` are different functions and should have different concerns, if `handleSUB` execution is completely controlled by `groupCheck`, then maybe the two functions should be just one combined function. If not, then yes, you do need `if else`.

Answer (score 0):

To bail out early, you can run the function inside the if condition to make it less verbose:

```
const handleSUB = () => {
  if(groupCheck())
    return;
  console.log("I ran")
}
```